# Docker-compose build error in dotnet-architecture eShopOnContainers project: "failed to solve: executor failed running"

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, docker-compose

I've cloned the Microsoft dotnet-architecture eShopOnContainers project and encountered an error while running "docker-compose build" command:

"failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o /app]: exit code: 1"

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

I need help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance!